# Error while exporting comments from Adobe Acrobat 9 Pro

Tags: windows-7, adobe-acrobat, microsoft-word-2013

I want to export the comments made on my PDF file into word format.
I'm using Windows 7 with Acrobat 9 Pro. I also have MS Office 2013 installed and running.
When I click on the **Comments** Menu and select **Export Comments to Word** - I get the following error.
[image]

Comment: What was installed later? Acrobat or MS Office? In the second case, try running the repair function in Acrobat.

Comment: how to run repair function in acrobat? MS office and Acrobat came installed from my MIS team - so i'm unaware of the sequence of installation

Comment: Repair should be under the Help menu. However, if your MIS team installed it, they may have suppressed it, and you'd have to talk to them.

Comment: I ran a repair as you suggested. Acrobat told me that PDF's must be tagged. I created a tagged PDF from within Acrobat. Re-tried the export comments options - the same dialog pops back at me again...